# harmonic, m-harmonic, hyperbolic-harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis

Anyone has any idea about harmonic, m-harmonic, and hyperbolic-harmonic functions?

Harmonic functions are characterized by mean value property, m-harmonic functions are characterized by volume mean value property.

I want to know the relationship between these three types of harmonic functions.

Answer (score 1):

Harmonic functions on a domain in $\mathbb R^n$ can be characterized either by the spherical mean value property or by ball mean value property: these properties are equivalent. (Indeed, ball means can be computed from spherical means, and vice versa). Therefore, m-harmonic functions are the same as harmonic.

Without context, it is hard to say what exactly is meant by hyperbolic harmonic functions here. One possibility is that these are harmonic maps into the unit disk $D\subset \mathbb C$ equipped with the hyperbolic metric $(1-|z|^2)^{-1} |dz|$. These are quite different from Euclidean harmonic functions: neither of two classes contains the other, and their intersection is rather small (constant functions only, I think).